# AWS Cognito - Creating multiple developer authenticated identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito. I can do the FB login, Google, Amazon, and even developer authenticated identity with no problem. However, I am using the developer authenticated identity to let the user log in with a third party, Spotify. As far as I know, Spotify does not use OpenID Connect, so I can't go that route, and it is not one of the supported identities in Cognito (only Facebook, Google and Amazon). I need to add another log in that is also not OpenID Connect compatible and not FB, Google or Amazon, but I can't figure out from the documentation and web console how to create more than one developer authenticated account domains or if it is even possible.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Amazon Cognito does not support multiple developer providers. You can post a feature request in our [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=173), it will help us prioritize features in our roadmap.

Thanks,
Rachit